# What's the difference between the following ways of adding elements to a c++ vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, push-back

Snippet1: The following snippet prints out 0 1 but returns an empty vector.

```
vector<int> trial() {
    vector<int> ret;
    ret.reserve(2);
    ret[0] = 0;
    ret[1] = 1;
    cout << ret[0] << " " << ret[1] << "\n";
    return ret;
}
```

Snippet 2: The following snippet prints out 0 1 and returns a vector contains {0,1}.

```
vector<int> trial() {
    vector<int> ret;
    ret.push_back(0);
    ret.push_back(1);
    cout << ret[0] << " " << ret[1] << "\n";
    return ret;
}
```

Why doesn't snippet 1 work like snippet 2. If I am reserving memory and adding values to the vector.

Comment: use `resize()`, not `reserve()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reserve()` does not change the vector size, what you want is `resize()` it.